# Can I use logical operators for hexadecimal comparisons?

Tags: c, embedded

I need to set PORTC to the temporary variable that is modified through a bunch of if statements, but the bit sequence assigned to PORTC at the very end are all zeroes so I assume that none of the expressions in the if statements were evaluated to true where I test whether the bit sequence is less than or equal to the hexadecimal.

```
#include <avr/io.h>

unsigned char GetBit(unsigned char x, unsigned char k) {
    return ((x & (0x01 << k)) != 0);
}

unsigned char SetBit(unsigned char x, unsigned char k, unsigned char b) {
    return (b ? x | (0x01 << k) : x & ~(0x01 << k));
}


int main(void)
{
    /* Replace with your application code */
    DDRA = 0x00; PORTA = 0x0F; 
    DDRC = 0xFF; PORTC = 0x00;
    unsigned char tmpa = 0x00;
    unsigned char tmpc = 0x00;

    tmpa = tmpa | PORTA;
    tmpc = tmpc | PORTC;

    while (1)
    {
        if (tmpa <= 0x02) //less than or equal to 2
        {
            SetBit(tmpc, 5, 1);
            SetBit(tmpc, 6, 1);
        }
        if (tmpa <= 0x04) //less than or equal to 4 
        {
            SetBit(tmpc, 4, 1);
            SetBit(tmpc, 6, 1);
        }
        if (tmpa <= 0x06) //less than or equal to 6
        SetBit(tmpc, 3, 1);
        if (tmpa <= 0x09) //less than or equal to 9
        SetBit(tmpc,2,1);
        if (tmpa <= 0x0C)
        SetBit(tmpc,1,1); //less than or equal to 12
        if (tmpa <= 0x0F)
        SetBit(tmpc,0,1); //less than or equal to 15

        PORTC = PORTC | tmpc; ////////PORTC ends up being all zeros
        asm("break");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are confusing representation of a value with the value itself. Operators work on values. It does not matter if they are represented as octal, decimal or hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: compile the code on your PC and use a debugger

Comment: I guess `PORTC` is some hardware register. Are you sure they are readable and writeable? You should check what you read before your `if` sequence and what value you have in `tmpc` before you write it.

Comment: You might also verify that your `setbit` function returns correct values. To be on safe side I would add brackets around the expressions left and right of the `:`

Comment: PORTC is a register than you can write to and the setbit function was from the lab instructions. I also used a debugger to determine that PORTC had all zeros.

Comment: Your body contains no question, and the answer to the title is clearly "yes" - the answer does not solve your problem.  You are asking the wrong question, an X-Y question; you should really ask why your calls to `setBit()` do not modify the argument.  Hexadecimal is merely a representation in the source code for human readability, at the machine binary level it is just an integer, the machine knows nothing about hex, decimal or octal.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the return value of `SetBit` is discarded.
Try changing the calls to this function as follows:

```
    SetBit(tmpc,0,1); //less than or equal to 15
```

to

```
    tmpc = SetBit(tmpc,0,1); //less than or equal to 15
```

Comment: super basic coding error and it works now, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

You can definetely use logical operators on hexadecimal values. It makes no difference whether the representaton is binary , hex or decimal. For your compiler it is an 8 bit value.

Regarding your example:
tmpa is 0x0F so only last if condition is verified. At this line tmpc is equal to 0x00 (after initialization). When passing through `SetBit(tmpc,0,1))` The condition will evaluate to true (b = 1) and the function will return `x | (0x01 << k` which in this case is equal to 0x01. 
tmpc is equal to 0x00 at the end (its initial value) because you are not assigning it to the return value of your SetBit function!
Try this :

```
if (tmpa <= 0x0F)
    tmpc = SetBit(tmpc,0,1); //less than or equal to 15
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use logical operators, but this code is needlessly slow and complicated. You don't need branches or comparisons, all you need is a look-up table with 16 values.

```
const uint8_t VAL [0x10] =
{
  [0x00] = 1u<<5 | 1u<<6,
  [0x01] = 1u<<5 | 1u<<6,
  [0x02] = 1u<<5 | 1u<<6,
  [0x03] = 1u<<4 | 1u<<6,
  [0x04] = 1u<<4 | 1u<<6,
  // ... up to 0x0F
};

tmpc = VAL[tmpa & 0xF];
```